# Not able to make ajax request in windows phone phonegap

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have developed  android app using phonegap. Now I am trying to use that code for developing windows phone 8 app. I have successfully set up the Visual Studio Express environment and made Cordova Template. After that I have created the project and inserted my assets into that project.

It shown me my app UI perfectly and events, page navigation are working fine. But it is not able to make ajax http connection. Do I need enable any thing in SDK or Project Directory.

When am I trying this , I am getting alert that 'Connectivity Failure'

This is my sample js code for making http connection

```
             $.ajax({
                 beforeSend: function() {        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a","Processing !!! Please wait "); },
                 complete:   function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); },
                 type: 'POST',
                 url:'http://192.168.12.175/Receiver.php', 
                 data: reqObj ,
                 success: function(data){
                 responseString=data;
                 } 
                 error: function(data){
                 //get the status code
             alert('Connectivity Failure');
                 } });
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a","Processing !!! Please wait ");

formData = {
    param1: param1
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "http://192.168.12.175/Receiver.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('Connectivity Failure');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this, I got same Connectivity Failure only. Do  i need to use/do any other extra thing . to make it work for windows phone 8. which was worked fine in android  (phonegap).

Answer (score 0):

Adding 
`<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>`
in config.xml fixed the issue for me.

This is adding the `<Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />` into WMAppManifest.xml file when build is generated